# Kibana textbox instead of dropdown

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

To create a new Kibana visualization I select "Controls" from the "New Visualization" section:

[image]

Viewing the "Controls" section:

[image]

An option does not appear to exist to add a "text field" , all field types are dropdowns. How to add a searchable text field type to a visualization ?

The reason I'm attempting to add a text field instead of a dropdown field is that the number of records returned by the field in question exceeds `1'000'000` and therefore I do not want to populate all data for performance reasons.

Up to this point I use `kibana.autocompleteTerminateAfter` and set the value to the number of data points stored in elastic for the field. I'm concerned that as more records are added to elastic the performance of loading the Kibana search page will decrease as `kibana.autocompleteTerminateAfter` will require updating as new records are added and could at some point be set to `kibana.autocompleteTerminateAfter : 10000000`

From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html :

[image]